# A simple(ish) proof for the lagrangian with one inequality constraint?

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I know the Lagrangian comes indirectly from the implicit function theorem (so don't worry about that nightmare) but does anyone know a good proof for the following theorem:

Consider the optimization problem of $ Max[f(x,y)]$ subject to $g(x,y) \le m$ Let $(a,b)$ be a solution and assume: 
1.The gradient vector of $g(a,b)$ does not equal zero. 
2.The implicit function theorem holds.

If $ f:R^2\to R$ and $g(x,y) \le m$ then there exists $ \lambda $ such that:

$ L(x, y, \lambda) = f(x,y) - \lambda(g(x,y) - m)$

$\frac{dL}{dx} = 0$ $\frac{dL}{dy} = 0$ $\lambda \ge 0$ and $\lambda(g(x,y) - m) = 0 $

Thanks!

Comment: as stated $f$ has nothing to do with $g$? And what is $L$?

Comment: My apologies, I guess I was trying to cut down on the Math commands a bit too much. Please find the edit. L is now explicitly stated as the Lagrangian and the optimization problem is more clearly defined.

Comment: Actually existence is not guaranteed (You need to assume that maximum is attained at some $(x, y)$, then the stated consequence occurs at that point).

Comment: Yes I'm assuming theres a solution point (a,b) for which this occurs, that the implicit function theorem holds and that the gradient vector at $g(a,b)$ does not equal zero.

Comment: You should  add these conditions to the statement of the theorem. For the proof, you can divide into two cases, according to whether $g(a,b)=m$, or $g(a,b)<m$.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint inequality and constraint just with  g(x,y) are similar problems.  The difference is that after solution is arrived at by Euler Lagrange, for  the inequality we can find a *boundary zone* when we had only a border line without inequality part $ \lambda(g(x,y) - m) $ in operation.